# Calling a function when the template is loaded in angular js

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ngroute

I've been going through a lot of answers here and i didn't find one relevant to my issue. I'm sorry if its already answered. I'm a newbie to angular js presently started working on angular routing.
I have an application which loads templates using $routeProvider and i need to call a function soon after the template gets loaded with all the images. Is that possible? Any simple Method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)** directive which calls a function required in your case.

Add `ng-init="yourfunction()"` somewhere at the starting point of the page.

```
<div ng-init="LoadThings()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngView $viewContentLoaded event that is emitted every time content is reloaded

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView